# Rails HTTP 204 not rendering template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My application has a search page, where results can (obviously) sometimes be zero. When the page returns results, I want to use HTTP 200, and when there are no results, I want the page to return HTTP 204.

This process works on the initial load, which is an synchronous call - if there are no results, the page renders properly, saying there are no results, with an HTTP status of 204.

However, if I perform a search which returns results via HTML, and then use my search filters to get a known empty result set, the AJAX call fires, hits the controller, and I see the logs return an HTTP 204, but the corresponding JS template (which re-renders the page) never loads (e.g. I continue to see a spinner I put in place to show that work is being done).

Is there something preventing Rails from rendering an AJAX template if the HTTP status code is 204?

Note: The app works fine with no results and using no `status: :no_content` directive.  But a 200 HTTP status with no results seems incorrect to me.

**Edit** - Corresponding code

After I filter my results, I paginate them (using `will_paginate`). The last line of my controller method is:

```
render :index, status: @results.total_entries.zero? ? :no_content : :ok
```

Comment: You'll need to add a bit of code here that describes how you assign the 204 code and where that might not be working.

Comment: @tadman - duh, thanks.  Done.

Comment: Are you seeing 204 in your `log/development.log` or is it the wrong code there?

Comment: How are you handling the ajax call in the page? Are you using jquey? using `sucess` callback? It looks like an issue in javascript side

Comment: @tadman Yes, I see the 204 in the `log/development.log` _after_ the `Render index.js` line is called.

Comment: @Aguardientico - It's through a remote form submission on the change of a filter, which calls the `index` controller method, then renders the `index.js` page, which contains jQuery. It works when the status code is 200, but not when it's 204.

Answer (score 0):

In rails 5 you need to specify response format manually in case for http `204: No content`.

More explanation you can find [here](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/07/03/controller-actions-default-no-content-in-rails-5-if-template-is-missing.html).

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2.7.1, not Rails 5.